# Collection schema for a quiz app in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections, schema

I am creating a quiz app in Meteor.

What can a schema for a question look like? I am thinking of doing something like

```
const QuestionSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  text: {
    type: String,
  },
  correctAnswers: {
    type: [Object],
  },
  'correctAnswers.$.text': {
    type: String,
  },
  wrongAnswers: {
    type: [Object],
  },
  'wrongAnswers.$.text': {
    type: String,
  },
});
```

but is it really smart? How can I save which answer some user chose?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define a separate schema for the answers.

```
var QuestionSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  text: {
    type: String
  },
  answers: [{
    type: SimpleSchema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'AnswerSchema'
  }]
});

var AnswerSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  text: {
    type: String
  },
  correct: {
    type: Boolean
  },
  question: {
    type: SimpleSchema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'QuestionSchema'
  }
});
```

If you need to track the answers a user picked, you'll have to store them in the user instance:

```
var UserSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  // Define other attributes here.
  answers: [{
    type: SimpleSchema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'AnswerSchema'
  }]
});
```

Comment: But how can I tell which answer the user selected?

Answer (score 0):

As @gnerkus suggests it's simpler to have a `correct` boolean for each answer but each answer also needs an `_id` so that you reference it, for example which answers did the user select?

```
const AnswerSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  _id: { type: String },
  text: { type: String },
  correct: { type: Boolean }
});

const QuestionSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  text: { type: String },
  answers: { type: [AnswerSchema] }
});
```